# NDB Filtering for Structured Property Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python

I have ndb models:

```
class Product(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    description = ndb.StringProperty()
    code = ndb.StringProperty()

class Category(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

class Shop(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    category = ndb.StructuredProperty(Category)
    address = ndb.StringProperty()

class ProductInShop(ndb.Model):
    product = ndb.StructuredProperty(Product)
    shop = ndb.StructuredProperty(Shop)
    price = ndb.FloatProperty()
```

And in a function I need find product in shop (product code and shop key in request). If no product in shop (returning None) then I need create it.
If it exist then update price value from request. Now I am making query by gql.

```
product_in_shop = ndb.gql(
        'SELECT * FROM ProductInShop WHERE \
product.code = :1 AND shop = :2 LIMIT 1',
        request.code,
        ndb.Key(Shop, request.shop_key).get()
    ).get()
```

And it works fine.
But! Some times `product_in_shop = None` when there are should be an entity (I was checked at database).
I was tried to make another query to count entities and it return 0, but there was more then 1 entity.

When I see this bag I can just update (python appcfg.py -A project-name update project-name) and it works...

Any ideas what I am doing wrong or how fix it?

Comment: I guess it's linked with eventual consistency. https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/structuring_for_strong_consistency

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely [Eventual Consistency](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/structuring_for_strong_consistency). When you design your system with Cloud Datastore, you need to plan for the case that these queries can take time to become up-to-date. Likely, redeploying your app in this case just takes enough time that the information is updated by the time you check again.

In order to guarantee strong consistency, you'll want to organize your data into Entity Groups. An important consideration for your data model is that within an EG you can query in a strongly consistent manner. However, you can only update a single entity group at a sustained rate of 1 update per second (this update could be a batch update though).

Try to align these entity groups along natural boundaries to help limit the rate that any given entity group will be written to as your application scales. For example, you might have a single entity group per user, or in the case of your application, perhaps a single entity group per `Shop`. If you put all `Product`s for a single `Shop` into one entity group, you can always list all `Product`s in a shop in a strongly consistent manner. You wouldn't be able to scale up the number of people adding items to a shop (you are limited to writes of products to a shop to one batch per second), but this would likely be an acceptable constraint on the system.

So considering the following layout instead:

```
class Product(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    description = ndb.StringProperty()
    code = ndb.StringProperty()

class Category(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

class Shop(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    category = ndb.StructuredProperty(Category)
    address = ndb.StringProperty()

class ProductInShop(ndb.Model):
    product = ndb.StructuredProperty(Product)
    price = ndb.FloatProperty()
```

When you create a `ProductInShop`, you'll want to set the parent to the key of the `Shop` that it is a part of. For example:

```
ProductInShop(parent=ndb.Key(Shop, request.shop_key),
    product=Product(...), price=10.0).put()
```

Then you can issue your query for one product in a given shop with a specific code:

```
product_in_shop = ndb.gql(
        'SELECT * FROM ProductInShop WHERE \
product.code = :1 AND ANCESTOR IS :2 LIMIT 1',
        request.code,
        ndb.Key(Shop, request.shop_key)
    ).get()
```

As a side note, if your `code` is unique to a single product, consider setting the id of the `ProductInShop` to be the code. Then you don't have to issue a query for this:

```
ProductInShop(id=product.code, product=product, price=10.0).put()
```

Then, you can lookup your `ProductInShop` without having to issue a query with:

```
product_in_shop = ndb.Key(Shop, request.shop_key, ProductInShop, request.code).get()
```